# Why does my array prints only the first element?

Tags: arrays, c

```
    double fun(int size) {

    double *arr = (double*)calloc(size, sizeof(double));
    assert(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf_s("%lf", &arr[i]);
    }
    return *arr;
    
    
}
void main() {
    int size = 5;
    printf("%lf", fun(size));
}
```

trying to print my array using the main function, it prints only the 1st element from the array..
someone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: You're only telling it to print one member.

Comment: You might want to rethink the return type of `fun`.

Comment: how do I return all the elements from the array without using another parameter in the function?

Comment: Arrays are not first-class types in C. You will need to return a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double fun(int size)`

Consider what the function is returning. A single double. The line `*arr` will get the value of the first element in the `arr` pointer and return it. What I think you mean to do is iterate over each element in a pointer to a double returned by the function.

```
double *fun(int size) {

  double *arr = (double*)calloc(size, sizeof(double));
  assert(arr);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    scanf_s("%lf", &arr[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}
void main() {
  int size = 5;
  double *arr = fun(size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%lf", arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work.. I cant call the function using the "*arr = fun(size)"

Comment: Yes that is correct, you can't. In its previous state you can only return a double. You need to modify the fun to return a double pointer. My syntax may have been confusing, but it's essentially (double *) arr, not (double) *arr. So of course "*arr = fun(size)" will not work.

Comment: I changed fun(size) from (double*) to (int*) , Now your solution works for me, thanks!